# How to update the actual true value="" of a input field when another field is entered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have reviewed tonnes of articles and all solutions only update the visually displayed value as opposed to the actual value within the input tag itself.

When I click on a button a modal appears with a text input to enter a code. We will call it input1

Upon entering the code and exiting the modal the button updates to the code entered and a hidden input value gets updated as well. However the actual tags value="" remains the same.

I have tried numerous ways but all seem to only update the visual and not the true value.

Here is what I have so far but it only updates the value you see in the browser not within the tag itself.

```js
let promoModal = document.getElementById("promoModal");
let promoBtn = document.getElementById("promo");
let promoSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("promoClose")[0];

promoBtn.onclick = function() {
  promoModal.style.display = "block";
}
promoSpan.onclick = function() {
  promoModal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == promoModal) {
    promoModal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function updatePromo() {
  let promoValue = document.getElementById("promo-value");
  let producePromo = document.getElementById("promo");
  let copyPromo = document.getElementById("promo-value-copy");
  producePromo.innerHTML = promoValue.value;
  copyPromo.innerHTML = promoValue.value;
}
```

```css
/* THE MODAL */

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 280px;
    position: relative;
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.adultClose,
.promoClose {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="promo" type="button" class="promo">
  <span class="promoCode">Promo Code +</span>
</button>
<input type="hidden" id="promo-value-copy" value="test">

<!-- Promo Modal -->
<div id="promoModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="promoClose">&times;</span>
    <input type="text" class="promo-value" id="promo-value" value="" placeholder="Promotional code" onchange="updatePromo()">
  </div>
</div>
```

I stripped the styling to get to the meat and potatoes.

How can I update the actual value="test" to the new value using javascript?

Comment: _"However the actual tags value="" remains the same."_ Which element are you referring to? id="promo-value-copy"?

Comment: If you want to change the value in the DOM, use `input1.setAttribute("value", newValue)`

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html. I think this will clear things up for you. Here's the important part: "The value property reflects the current text-content inside the input box, whereas the value attribute contains the initial text-content of the value attribute from the HTML source code"

Comment: @Barmar you rock, that was exactly the issue. I just couldn't get the wording right to be able to properly research. If you wanted to make it a answer I will mark it as correct. I just added it to my updatePromo function and we are golden.

Comment: thx @AndreNuechter that stack is a good read, I will surely review tonight over a cuppa :)

Comment: [Input](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element) shouldn't have children, it has a`content model` of `nothing` in the spec which says *When an element's content model is nothing, the element must contain no Text nodes (other than inter-element whitespace) and no element nodes.*

Answer (score 0):

The innerHTML is used for changing HTML content, so for instance you can use it for changing the content of a paragraph `<p id="text-to-change"></p>`.
To change the input `value` you can use the `.value` property of the object.

Try to change the following line `copyPromo.innerHTML = promoValue.value;` with `copyPromo.value = promoValue.value;`

Comment: unfortunately i need them in both locations. The solution I went with is above. Thanks for the assist though :)

Comment: You need to change only the last line of the updatePromo() function. The rest is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (also chosen by the original asker) is buried [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70870403/how-to-update-the-actual-true-value-of-a-input-field-when-another-field-is-en#comment125288355_70870403), by @Barmar:

> If you want to change the value in the DOM, use `input1.setAttribute("value", newValue)`

Answer (score -1):

so going with Barmar's suggestion I was able to update my updatePromo function to both produce the value as well as update the DOM value.

Here is the updated function. I hope it helps the community.

```
 function updatePromo() {
   let promoValue = document.getElementById("promo-value");
   let producePromo = document.getElementById("promo");
   let copyPromo = document.getElementById("promo-value-copy");
   producePromo.innerHTML = promoValue.value;
   copyPromo.innerHTML = promoValue.value;
   copyPromo.setAttribute("value", promoValue.value); // suggestion given by Barmar

 }
```

I had to leave the other element as it adds the text after the form field which is actually needed for this project however typically would not be needed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the value like this:

```
   document.getElementById("promo-value-copy").value = promoValue.value;
```

Comment: as mentioned in the other response with the same answer I cannot remove/replace this element unfortunately. I decided to go with Barman's suggestion which has worked for my needs. thanks.